# Is there any way to run multiple read processes for a single redis datastore?

Tags: redis

I am currently running redis using a single instance of `redis-server`. My application is about 10% writes, and the rest is reads. I'm a bit new to redis, but IIUC, the single threaded nature of redis means that each request is processed serially, so eg. Read #1 will be processed in full before Read #2, and so on. This seems leave room for improvement in terms of performance, since the reads will block for a long time on memory latency, and they could instead be executed in parallel.

Does redis have a solution for this? Is there a way to achieve higher capacity via parallel processing of read requests?

Comment: Have you actually tested before assuming you need parallelization? Do you have any estimates regarding the peak throughout that you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create read-only slaves (replications) to off-load the reads. So each request can be routed to a different instance.

Also, multiple slaves can run on a single machine.

See [Redis Replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication)